# Ubuntu UUID error dropping to a shell

Tags: 20.04, uuid

```
ALERT! UUID=XXX does not exist. Dropping to a shell.
```

So I got this error. I found several solutions on forums to change from RAID to AHCI. I don't have that option (Acer Laptop). The SSD is recognized by the bios. But when booting from a love USB stick I can't find it (via disks or blkid)

But when I insert the SSD into another PC I can boot from it without any problems?!

This is the output from the other PC:

```
blkid
/dev/nvme0n1p1: UUID="2218-1E76" TYPE="vfat" PARTUUID="70498a4c-2e76-4d33-aa06-35a1f56d6f30"
```

I tried this also this solution:
https://www.howtogeek.com/114884/how-to-repair-grub2-when-ubuntu-wont-boot/

It restored the GRUB and I still boot with the drive from another PC.

I think there is some type of connection bricked :/

Do you have any ideas?

BR Tim

Comment: DO you have a bootable Ubuntu install media? If yes; boot it and use "Try ubuntu" mode, does the SSD appear when listing devices (e.g. using `lsblk` in bash/shell/terminal )

Comment: Yes I di and no it did not an that laptop but in the other PC it did… I found the solution tho

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So like a lot of other answers from forums was `RAID -> AHCI` in `BIOS`. I did not have that option and `Ctrl+S` didn’t work.

I got so frustrated that I spammed `Ctrl+S` quite some time and alas, the option appeared. Switching to `AHCI` fixed the issue (I disabled the `secureboot` too)